# How to add rows with identical items in different columns in Pandas together

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample dataframe that looks like below. I'd like to eventually group row 1 and row 3 together, since they contain identical items in different columns.

```
x    y      count
a,b  b,a      5
a,c  c,a      2
b,a  a,b      1
```

I've spent a lot of time trying to solve this, but have not encountered a good solution yet. What steps should I take to reach the below final dataframe?

```
x    y      count
a,b  b,a      5+1
a,c  c,a      2
```

Comment: do you need the actual sum (6) or just 5+1?

Comment: kindly provide source code to recreate the dataframe. @DanailPetrov's question is important too

Comment: I'd like to get the actual sum. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
df.groupby((df.x + df.y).str.replace(',', '').apply(lambda x: ''.join(sorted(x)))
           ).agg({'x': 'first', 'y': 'first', 'count': sum}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

OUTPUT:

```
     x    y  count
0  a,b  b,a      6
1  a,c  c,a      2
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different approach.

Sort x and y rowwise using [`np.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html#numpy-sort) on axis=1:

```
cols = ['x', 'y']
df[cols] = np.sort(df[cols].values, axis=1)
```

```
     x    y  count
0  a,b  b,a      5
1  a,c  c,a      2
2  a,b  b,a      1
```

Then a standard [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate):

```
df = df.groupby(cols, as_index=False).aggregate(count=('count', 'sum'))
```

```
     x    y  count
0  a,b  b,a      6
1  a,c  c,a      2
```

---

Complete Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': ['a,b', 'a,c', 'b,a'],
    'y': ['b,a', 'c,a', 'a,b'],
    'count': [5, 2, 1]
})

cols = ['x', 'y']
df[cols] = np.sort(df[cols].values, axis=1)
df = df.groupby(cols, as_index=False).aggregate(count=('count', 'sum'))
```